# Why does a function named sum1 output "REF"?

Tags: excel, vba

This VBA code works.

```vb
Function vsum(x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer)
    vsum = x + y + z
End Function
```

This VBA code outputs "REF".

```vb
Function sum1(x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer)
    sum1 = x + y + z
End Function
```

Comment: Please post some screenshots too. Based on your current question, is impossible to solve your problem

Comment: Did you define "vsum" and not define "sum1" ?

Answer (score 3):

Excel thinks "SUM1" is an address, even if you define it as a function. You can tell this is the case when typing it in:

[image]

You can see the letters are black, this is still a function. But add any number:

[image]

And it turns blue, so excel thinks this is an address of a cell somewhere far far far to the right. You can do this with other 1-3 letter combinations as well:

[image]

So excel thinks these are addresses, you have to give your functions longer names.

Comment: *"longer names"* I would precise to *"meaningful names"*. Like `Sum1` no one has any idea what it does, but with something like `SumOfItems` or `SumOf3Numbers` it describes better what the function does. This means it is easier to read and understand and therefore leads to less errors.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I agree, but when it comes to eliminating the error, any 4 letters will do it (or anything that ends with a letter actually). It's definitely a good idea to name your functions something sensible.